# Example of a bijective continuous map between Banach spaces whose inverse is not continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, inverse-function, open-map

What would be an easy example of a bijective continuous map between Banach spaces whose inverse is not continuous?

A usual example of a bijective continuous function between metric spaces would be $f(x)=x^2$ on $(-1,0]\cup[1,2]$, where $f^{-1}$ does map the connected set $[0,4]$ to the unconnected set $(-1,0]\cup[1,2]$ and hence is not continuous.

But I fail to come up with an example, where the domain and range are Banach spaces.

Comment: I have not checked it, but one of the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3713667/an-example-of-a-complete-metric-space-x-and-a-function-f-x-to-x-which-is-a) has an example.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Severins' example does.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you for the comment. I worked through the answer by Severin and found that except for one typo the argument works fine. The typo: $dist(S,y_n)=\frac 1 {n+1}$. I think it should be $dist(S,y_n)=\frac 1 {n+4}$.